# Array index not working in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures

I have absolutely no idea of whats happening. But when I try to iterate in this, using [i] on line 12, it doesn´t work and I get the span I want to write in totally blank. But, without changing anything else, only switching [i] to [0] on line 12, for example, I get my span written as expected!

Any ideas?

```
$(function() {  
    var listaCoisas = [
        "disruptiva",
        "matadora",
        "feroz",
        "tradicional"
    ];

    var i;
    for (i=0; i<listaCoisas.length; i++){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#word-attribute').empty().append(listaCoisas[3]);
        },1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: setTimeout is asynchronous .. by the time the code in the callback is called, `i == listaCoisas.length` for modern browsers, change `var i;
    for (i=0;...` to `for let i=0;...` or, try using `listaCoisas.forEach` instead

Comment: The thing is that I really needed to use settimeout (or any delay). Is there a way to make it synchronous?

Comment: Did you even try either suggestion? You can still use settimeout

Comment: i tried the foreach and didnt work. im investigating about for let. sorry for asking before trying both.

Comment: You possibly used foreach  wrong

Comment: `listaCoisas.forEach(function(entry){
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('#word-attribute').empty().append(entry);
  },1000);
 });`

Comment: that looks correct, what's wrong with it? are you expecting each iteration to be completed 1 second after the previous? `listaCoisas.forEach(function(entry, i){ 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#word-attribute').empty().append(entry); 
    },(i+1) * 1000); 
});`

Comment: exactly that. thats why i wanted to make settimeout synchronous.

Comment: you can't change asynchronous to synchronous - edited previous comment to show the simplistic way to do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want each iteration to be 1 second after the previous, you need to change the setTimeout delay - using `forEach`

```
listaCoisas.forEach(function(entry, i){ 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#word-attribute').empty().append(entry); 
    },(i+1) * 1000); 
});
```

Comment: Got it! The idea is to sort of set all timings until callback runs. thanks!

Comment: well, the idea is to separate each iteration of `$('#word-attribute').empty().append(entry);` by 1 second - so the first runs after 1 second, the second after 2 seconds, etc all the setTimeout's are "started" at almost the same time

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works well when it replaces the for loop in your code but adding the staggered delays alone would not make the original code above work and I think it is important to understand why.

Because of [closures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQqwU2Ixu-U), by the time your first setTimeout is called, the for loop will have already run and the value of `i` will be one more than the last item in your array (4th index). This means nothing will ever get appended to `#word-attribute` as it will try to append an item that doesn't exist. If you open up the console [here](https://jsbin.com/copozex/edit?html,js,output) you can see the problem.

There are a couple of things you could do if you wanted to keep the for loop beyond adding the delayed setTimeouts:

1. If you are compiling your javascript using something like Babel then you can take advantage of the ES6 let keyword which carries its own closure with it. Using `let` instead of `var` for `i`. [Example](https://jsbin.com/yirowuviye/edit?html,js,output)
2. Use an anonymous function to create another closure around the `i` variable which we will call `x` inside the anonymous function. setTimeout will then have access to the correct value of `i` when it is called. [Example](https://jsbin.com/tenaxap/edit?html,js,output)